# Are inverse relationships needed for predicates to work for core data?

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, predicate

Hi I'm very new to ios and I was wondering why I wasn't able to filter my results using this:

```
predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(pi.employee.last CONTAINS[c] %@)", searchText];
```

do inverse relationships need to be set for this predicate to work? In other words do i need a property from employee to  to pi and from pi to Fetched Entity for this predicate to work?

thanks in advance

Comment: The missing inverse relationship is most probably *not* the cause for the failing predicate (although you should have one for other reasons). - I would suggest that you show more information about your entities, attributes and relationships, and then rephrase the question to "Why does this predicate not work?", instead of *assuming* that the missing inverse relationship is the reason.

Comment: Also, it would be nice if you were to explain how your predicate failed. Did you receive an error? Are you getting incorrect results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Figured out the problem. First and Last are reserved words.

Comment: You should add more detail about the answer. Reserved words in custom value expressions: If you use a custom value expression, you must escape reserved words such as SIZE, FIRST, and LAST using a # (for example, $source.#size). From document [Mapping Overview - Core Data Model Versioning and Data Migration Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/vmMappingOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004399-CH5-SW1)